# No module named 'django.urls' django 1.8

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

views.py

```
from nba.models import News
from nba.serializers import NewsSerializers

from rest_framework import viewsets


# Create your views here.
class NewsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = News.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NewsSerializers
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from nba import views

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'news', views.NewsViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/', include('router.urls')),
]
```

my django version is 1.8.

When I visited http://127.0.0.1:8000/api I got No module named 'django.urls' what should i do

Comment: You should upgrade to Django 2.0. Django 1.8 will stop receiving security updates *next month*, and this looks like a new project.

Comment: So this problem is about my Django version?Yep I try to use Django rest-framework and ajax

Comment: Yes, that’s what the problem is too.

Comment: DRF 3.7 stoped supporting Django < 1.10.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted, there is no evidence to justify the error you describe. You should post the error to find out which line in which file contains the relevant import.

By all means, upgrade to Django 1.11, it is the current [LTS Django release](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2015/jun/25/roadmap/).

`django.urls` exists from Django 1.10. Until then, it was `django.core.urlsresolvers`.

[Django 1.10 release notes:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.10/)

> Importing from the django.core.urlresolvers module is deprecated in
>   favor of its new location, django.urls.

[From the relevant doc page:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/)

> Deprecated since version 1.10: In older versions, these functions are
>   located in django.core.urlresolvers. Importing from the old location
>   will continue to work until Django 2.0.